# Formik handleReset for spesific Select's with one value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, react-select

I am using React.js with TypeScript.
I also use `react-select` component inside `Formik`. My problem is I want to reset some spesific Select components by button click. I have 2 issues here:

1. Seems that `props.handleReset` doesn't work when `Select` is `not multi`. How can I use if for Single Selects?
2. How can I tell `props.handleReset` to reset only spesific fields?

This is part of my code:

```
<Select
  className="react-select"
  isMulti={false}
  closeMenuOnSelect={false}
  options={this.props.selectOptions.faculties}
  placeholder={T.t('gen_select_faculty')}
  value={this.props.selectOptions.faculties.find((f) => f.value === props.values.faculty_id)}
  onChange={(option: any) => {
    props.setFieldValue('faculty_id', option.value);
    props.setFieldValue('faculty', option);
  }}
  noOptionsMessage={(): string => T.t('gen_select_no_faculty')}
/>

<button
  type="button"
  data-dismiss="modal"
  onClick={props.handleReset}
  aria-label="alert-success"
>
  RESET
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is the solution:

**1.** For handling single `Select` element by `props.handleReset`, you need to include `isClearable={true}` and also option of `null` for `value`, as example below:

`

```
<Select
  className="react-select"
  isMulti={false}
  isClearable={true}
  closeMenuOnSelect={false}
  options={this.props.selectOptions.faculties}
  value={props.values.faculties || null}
  onChange={(option: any) => {
    props.setFieldValue('faculty_id', option.value);
    props.setFieldValue('faculty', option);
  }}
/>
```